# Group data for only one department and leave the other on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table y that has data, i would like to group data where department = 1 and wherever the department = 0 to be left independent;

My table before the query

```
labref     department

  x          1
  x          1
  x          1
  x          0
  x          0
  x          0
```

How the result should look like after query

```
labref     department

  x          1
  x          0
  x          0
  x          0
```

the query i have tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM `y` 
WHERE labref='x' 
group by department 
Having department='1'
```

suggestions!

Comment: Could this question be more obscure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @kordirko's answer is very close, just he didn't group the  use

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM y
WHERE department = 1
group by department
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM y
WHERE department = 0
```

But you could also simpy use

```
SELECT * 
from y
group by if(y.department = 1, y.department, y.id)
```

(or the primary key of table y).

To get better answers, just give a bit more realistic queries - `select * ... group by` is not really your query I think.

Answer (score 1):

Use two queries and combine their results using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM y
WHERE department = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM y
WHERE department = 0
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/149f83/5

Comment: I can only guess here, but probably he has some columns to make a `group by` different from `select distinct` in his real problem.